# VLC won't play video from /tmp directory

Tags: video, vlc, snap, tmp

I have a video located at `/tmp/example.mp4`. When I try to play it with VLC I get the following error:

> Your input can't be opened:
>     VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///tmp/example.mp4'. Check the log for details.

When I check the log it contains the following error-level entry:

```
filesystem error: cannot open file /tmp/example.mp4 (No such file or directory)
```

However that file *does* exist:

```
$ ls /tmp/example.mp4 
/tmp/example.mp4
```

Furthermore, when I copy that file to my home folder I can play it without any problems. Why can't VLC play the video from the `/tmp` folder?

---

- **VLC version:** 3.0.8
- **OS version:** Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (4.4.0-173-generic)

Output from `ffprobe`:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'example.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:10.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 37 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480, 36 kb/s, 4 fps, 4 tbr, 16384 tbn, 8 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Comment: Is this a snap? A deb? Something else? For a snap, this seems like expected behavior.

Comment: @user535733 I installed it via `sudo snap install vlc`. Why is this expected behavior then? What is the difference?

Comment: Snaps run *confined* by design. They don't have access to most of your system. They can see your /home (nobody else's), and they can see their own /snap. And (essentially) nothing else in the filesystem. This issue pops up for most folks when they use /tmp or try to mount external media that the snap simply cannot see. It's not a bug - it was designed that way (security). Lot of discussion among developers about what to do this going on at http://snapcraft.io.

Comment: I totally agree with @user535733 so what you can do is to uninstall the snap version of VLC with `sudo snap remove vlc` and install the DEB package from the Ubuntu official repository with `sudo apt-get install vlc`

Answer (score 3):

GREAT the answer of user @user535733 and Raffa is correct and solve the problem!!!

Then: uninstall the snap version of VLC with

```
sudo snap remove vlc
```

and install the Debian (`.deb`) package from the Ubuntu official repository with

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```