# VLC cannot open .mp4 file in Thunderbird (mail)

Tags: sound

Running under Ubuntu 20,04 LTS.
The default Video application cannot play .MP4 video file, so I changed my default application from Video to VLC.
Now I can play a registered .MP4 video file without problem. But I cannot open a .MP4 video attachment directly in Thunderbird (mail). I have to register the file first. Then I can open the file from the folder where it has been saved. Is there a solution?

VLC error message is:
Your input media cannot be opened: VLC cannot open --file://tmp/pid-3078/VID-20220318-WA0083-1.mp4--  Verify messages in the journal for more details.

I don't know where is that journal.

Note: All .mp4 files are present in ..//tmp/pid-3078/

Comment: Hello. Two things first the location of the journal is a VLC question that have a very good support site. Second until the file is saved from the email it is not accessible that is normal. I suggest you may want to address this issue with VLC support.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217855/vlc-wont-play-video-from-tmp-directory

Comment: Have you saved the file to your computer? You be able to open the media file with VLC if you have downloaded the file. That is my recommendation.

Comment: did you install vlc as a snap? If so, then it isn't able to access files stored anywhere outside your /home. This file is saved in /tmp when you open it (most likely 3078 is the pid of Thunderbird, and it stores its attachments there before they are saved), and snap packages are restricted in which files they can access. Either save the file or get the deb version of vlc.

Comment: Please note that I can specify in preferences of Tnunderbird what to do with each type of attachment. For example a Word Document, open with LibreOffice Writer, a .jpeg file open with Visionneuse d'image, .mp4 open with VLC.